# Type 'Observable<UI[] | Promise<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UI[]>'. Type 'UI[] | Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'UI[]'

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-observable

I need to return a list of UI and I do this method:

```
getList(): Observable<UI[]> { 
        return this.httpClient.get("/api/listui").pipe(map(
            (response:Response) => {  return response.json(); },
        ),
            catchError((error) => { return throwError(error); }));
    }
```

In my vs code the error appears as:

"`Type 'Observable<UI[] | Promise<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UI[]>'.   Type 'UI[] | Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'UI[]'`."

Anyone can help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpClient will return json data by default you don't need to do this `return response.json();`

```js
getList(): Observable<UI[]> { 
        return this.httpClient.get("/api/listui").pipe(
            catchError((error) => { return throwError(error); }));
    }
```